# Shadow DOM vs Detached Elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, shadow-dom

So, I am hearing the phrase "shadow DOM" a lot now. Is that the same as a detached DOM element?

If I create a DOM element like this:

```
var $pizza = $('<aside>', {
   'class': 'pizza'
});
```

$pizza is detached. I can attach it using `attach`, `append` or `html` perhaps.

Is this functionally the same as the concept of shadow DOM, but with some other caveats? What are the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shadow DOM spec has been implemented in Chrome very recently (25). Shadow DOM is a spec covered by a larger group of "HTML5" specs known as Web Components. Web Components essentially allow for development of encapsulated widgets without resorting to iframes. Shadow DOM is a big part of this. There is already a neat polyfill for this spec included among other similar polyfills in Google's brand new Polymer library. Have a look at http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/ for some more detail on the subject. Note that the referenced article was written before the spec was implemented anywhere.

Addressing your question directly, detached elements and shadow DOM are not the same concepts.

Comment: To add to what Ray said, They're very different. Shadow DOM gives you the tools to encapsulate markup and hide it away from users. It's what the elements like `<video>` and `<input type="date">` use to hide away the UI of the video controls and date picker, respectively. Browser vendors have used it for a long time. Now, it's something web developers can use.

Comment: Cool! I'll accept this. After reading around a bit, I also found this article useful: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/

It reminds me of flex/flash custom components back in the day. Other libraries have similar concepts. Cool!